# adding python virtual environment to jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I have python 3.7 64 bit installed on my machine with Jupiter notebook.
Recently I needed to install 32 bit of python 3.6 .
I've created new virtual environment via Pycharm .
Then I've installed ipykernel and added kernel.
It was added successfully when I open Jupiter notebook I see the virtual environment but when I open
new notebook with new kernel, Jupiter notebook still runs 64 bit version of Python.

Does anyone knows how to solve it?